# Need an explanation on a shift syntax in code - C++

Tags: c++, syntax, sizeof

I need some further explanation on a code I don't quite understand.

This is a program that takes a `num = 25` and starts moving it left with a `<<` syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Shift to the left" << endl;

    short numb = 25;

    cout << "Starting value: ";

    for (int i = sizeof(short)*8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << (((1 << i) & numb) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
    cout << " " << numb << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(short)*8; i++){
        numb <<= 1;
        cout << "Shift" << (i+1 < 10 ? "0" : "")
                         << i+1 << "        : ";

        for (int i = sizeof(short)*8 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << (((1 << i) & numb) == 0 ? "0" : "1");
        cout << " " << numb << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

After the line where the first for loop is executed (the count line), what value does the & syntax takes into consideration? *((1 << i) & numb)*
I don't understand how the program can take *((1 << i) & numb)*, compares the two and return a value.

Also why do we declare i to be sizeof(short)*8 - 1? Why don't we just type in 16-1? Is there a specific reason to do this or is it just to make the code look more complex? 
And an explanation on why we even declare i to be 15-1 would be highly appreciative.

Hope I haven't given you too much, I'm a beginner and I need some guidance with some problems to which answers I can't still yet come up with by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: `sizeof(short)` is not guaranteed to be `2`.

Comment: `& syntax` here is *bitwise and* operator

Comment: `sizeof(short) * 8` is the number of bits in a `short`. `8` should really be `CHAR_BIT`. `sizeof(short) * 8 - 1` is the number of bits one has to left-shift `1` to get a value where the highest bit of a `short` is set. `((1 << i) & numb)` yields `0` when the bit at position `i + 1` is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bitwise shift operators are the `right-shift operator (>>)`, which moves the bits of shift_expression to the right, and the `left-shift operator (<<)`, which moves the bits of shift_expression to the left. There are also two complex operators that can be used to assign the value directly to the value on left. These are the `<<= operator` and the `>>= operator`.

The left-shift operator causes the bits in shift-expression to be shifted to the left by the number of positions specified by additive-expression. The bit positions that have been vacated by the shift operation are zero-filled. A left shift is a logical shift (the bits that are shifted off the end are discarded, including the sign bit).

The right-shift operator causes the bit pattern in shift-expression to be shifted to the right by the number of positions specified by additive-expression. For unsigned numbers, the bit positions that have been vacated by the shift operation are zero-filled. For signed numbers, the sign bit is used to fill the vacated bit positions. In other words, if the number is positive, 0 is used, and if the number is negative, 1 is used.

**Demo Code:**

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int a = 1, b = 3;

   // a right now is 00000001
   // Left shifting it by 3 will make it 00001000, ie, 8
   a = a << 3;
   cout << a << endl; // Gives output 8

   // Right shifting a by 2 will make it 00000010, ie, 2
   a = a >> 2;
   cout << a << endl;  // Gives output 2
   return 0;
}
```

The result of a right-shift of a signed negative number is implementation-dependent. If you left-shift a signed number so that the sign bit is affected, the result is undefined.